# Finding accumulated weight from two tables with different timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the accumulated weight during a period from two tables with different timestamps. The data in the SQL Server tables is logged from machines that I have no control over. current_product_weight is a table with product weight when product is changed but I see some data are repeated by the machine. total_pouches is number of pouches that keeps increasing (assuming no reset)

current_product_weight

| t_stamp | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1/10/2023 08:20:10 | 5.5 |
| 1/10/2023 08:26:34 | 5.5 |
| 1/10/2023 09:01:22 | 1.75 |
| 1/10/2023 12:04:06 | 1.75 |
| 1/10/2023 18:32:29 | 1.75 |
| 1/10/2023 19:21:44 | 3 |
| 1/11/2023 01:36:34 | 5.5 |
| 1/11/2023 03:44:17 | 5.5 |
| 1/11/2023 04:25:56 | 5.5 |

total_pouches

| t_stamp | pouches |
| --- | --- |
| 1/10/2023 08:00:00 | 0 |
| 1/10/2023 09:00:00 | 10 |
| 1/10/2023 10:00:00 | 20 |
| 1/10/2023 11:00:00 | 30 |
| 1/10/2023 12:00:00 | 50 |
| 1/10/2023 13:00:00 | 100 |
| 1/10/2023 14:00:00 | 150 |
| 1/10/2023 15:00:00 | 160 |
| 1/10/2023 16:00:00 | 170 |
| 1/10/2023 17:00:00 | 180 |
| 1/10/2023 18:00:00 | 190 |
| 1/10/2023 19:00:00 | 200 |
| 1/10/2023 20:00:00 | 210 |
| 1/10/2023 21:00:00 | 220 |
| 1/10/2023 22:00:00 | 230 |
| 1/10/2023 23:00:00 | 240 |

I would like to have a result like this for the period between 1/10/2023 08:00:00 and 1/10/2023 20:00:00, the accumulated_weight is approximated since the machine doesn't tell exactly when the pouches are produced.

| t_stamp | accumulated_weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1/10/2023 08:00:00 | 0 |
| 1/10/2023 09:00:00 | 55 |
| 1/10/2023 10:00:00 | 72.5 |
| 1/10/2023 11:00:00 | 90 |
| 1/10/2023 12:00:00 | 125 |
| 1/10/2023 13:00:00 | 212.5 |
| 1/10/2023 14:00:00 | 300 |
| 1/10/2023 15:00:00 | 317.5 |
| 1/10/2023 16:00:00 | 335 |
| 1/10/2023 17:00:00 | 352.5 |
| 1/10/2023 18:00:00 | 370 |
| 1/10/2023 19:00:00 | 387.5 |
| 1/10/2023 20:00:00 | 417.5 |

For example, the 3rd row is calculated as (20-10)*1.75+55 = 72.5

I have tried this, but it didn't give me the right result.

```
select t_stamp, ([pouches]-lag([pouches]) * weight over (order by [t_stamp]) as 
accumulated_weight
from current_product_weight
inner join total_pouches on current_product_weight.t_stamp = total_pouches.t_stamp
where t_stamp between '1/10/2023 08:00:00' and '1/10/2023 20:00:00'
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: I recommend using table aliases to make your query clearer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain, in words please, how you got your `accumulated_weight`values of 55 and 72.5 from the sample data you provided.

Comment: I get the accumulation: 5.5 x 10 pouches would return 55 for the hour of 9am then add 1.75 x 20 pouches returns 72.5 for 10 am. How would you determine that weights are duplicated? How to ignore the repeated weights when they are different timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Cte to join table and get the pouche and weight.
Second cte is to get the coeficient weight, and using `last_value(weight) ignore nulls` to replace null weight with the previous weight since not every time the weight exist.

then we use the cumulative sum `sum() over()` to get `accumulated_weight`.

```
with cte as (
  select t.t_stamp as t_stamp, max(t.pouches) as pouches, max(cpw.weight) as weight
  from total_pouches t 
  left join current_product_weight cpw on DATEPART(HOUR, cpw.t_stamp) = DATEPART(HOUR, t.t_stamp) -1
  where t.t_stamp between '1/10/2023 08:00:00' and '1/10/2023 20:00:00'
  group by t.t_stamp
),
cte2 as (
  select *,
  lag(pouches, 1, 0) over (order by t_stamp) as coef_weight,
  last_value(weight) ignore nulls over (order by t_stamp) sum_weight
  from cte
)
select t_stamp, sum((pouches - coef_weight) * sum_weight) over (order by t_stamp) as accumulated_weight
from cte2
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z47luCBA)